# How to set y-axis in HighChart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to display the death rate. Comparison of death between Male and Female deaths with respect to age is already done and displayed.

Issue I'm facing is the values in y-axis of chart. Y-axis in the chart is the horizontal one. I want it to display values like `...,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,...`

```js
var categories = [
                    '0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40',
                    '40-50', '50-60', '60-70', '70-80', '80-90',
                    '90+'
                ];

Highcharts.chart('male-female', {
    chart: { type: 'bar' },
    title: { text: 'Male Female Death Rate' },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: categories,
        reversed: false,
        labels: { step: 1 },
        accessibility: { description: 'Age (male)' } 
    },
    { // mirror axis on right side
        opposite: true,
        reversed: false,
        categories: categories,
        linkedTo: 0,
        labels: { step: 1 },
        accessibility: { description: 'Age (female)' }
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        series: { stacking: 'normal' }
    },

    series: [
        {
            name: 'Male',
            data: [ 0, -2, -1, 0, -2, -2, -1, -4, -6, -3 ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 3, 1, 9, 4 ]
        }
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="male-female"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Math.abs()` in your label formatter to get the absolute value.

Your `yAxis` must be set to :

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Math.abs(this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the same idea for the tooltip by using the `formatter` function.

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
      'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 1);
  }
}
```

```js
var categories = [
  '0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40',
  '40-50', '50-60', '60-70', '70-80', '80-90',
  '90+'
];

Highcharts.chart('male-female', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Male Female Death Rate'
  },
  xAxis: [{
      categories: categories,
      reversed: false,
      labels: {
        step: 1
      },
      accessibility: {
        description: 'Age (male)'
      }
    },
    { // mirror axis on right side
      opposite: true,
      reversed: false,
      categories: categories,
      linkedTo: 0,
      labels: {
        step: 1
      },
      accessibility: {
        description: 'Age (female)'
      }
    }
  ],
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Math.abs(this.value);
      }
    },
    tickInterval: 1
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
        'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 1);
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Male',
      data: [0, -2, -1, 0, -2, -2, -1, -4, -6, -3]
    },
    {
      name: 'Female',
      data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 3, 1, 9, 4]
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="male-female"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: this really helped, by adding `tickInterval: 1` in y-axis definition code will be more than perfect

Answer (score 2):

Another solution which you can implement is a creating an array with wanted ticks and use the **yAxis.tickPositions** feature to apply it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mb5v2w1u/

code:

```
var ticks = [];
for(let i = -10; i <=10; i++){
    ticks.push(i)
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Answer (score 1):

Try using `yAxis.labels.formatter` and `Math.abs()`

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels.formatter

```
yAxis: {
  tickInterval: 1, 
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Math.abs(this.value);
    }
  }
},
```

```js
var categories = [
  '0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40',
  '40-50', '50-60', '60-70', '70-80', '80-90',
  '90+'
];

Highcharts.chart('male-female', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Male Female Death Rate'
  },
  xAxis: [{
      categories: categories,
      reversed: false,
      labels: {
        step: 1
      },
      accessibility: {
        description: 'Age (male)'
      }
    },
    { // mirror axis on right side
      opposite: true,
      reversed: false,
      categories: categories,
      linkedTo: 0,
      labels: {
        step: 1
      },
      accessibility: {
        description: 'Age (female)'
      }
    }
  ],

  yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1, 
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Math.abs(this.value);
      }
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },

  series: [{
      name: 'Male',
      data: [0, -2, -1, 0, -2, -2, -1, -4, -6, -3]
    },
    {
      name: 'Female',
      data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 3, 1, 9, 4]
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="male-female"></div>
</figure>
```